# React - Cannot access fetched data outside useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I am trying to fetch data from a NodeJS server I created in React using the useEffect hook and the fetch API. the problem is I cannot access this data outside the useEffect callbacks
This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [LCS_Data, setLCSData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/lcs")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.LCS.info);
        setLCSData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  // console.log(LCS_Data.LCS.info);

  return <div className="main"></div>;
};

export default App;
```

and this the output of the two console.logs in the useEffect: [output of first console.log in the broswer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv8jI.png)

So everything is working fine, the data is structured as it should be and it is not corrupted in any way

that is until I uncomment the console.log before the return statement

it throws of this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOxOj.png)

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'info')

pointing at the last console.log when clearly the data is there.

How can I access properties inside my data object outside the scope of the useEffect hook so I can normally use it in my app

Comment: Your `console.log` will be executed before the fetch completes. `fetch` is async, as are state updates. You need to handle rendering before the data has been retrieved.

Comment: You could use optional chaining to prevent the error: `console.log(LCS_Data?.LCS?.info);`

Answer (score 1):

In the first render, `LCS_Data` has the value you provided in your `useState` (`{}`). `useEffect` only runs after your render, so when we reach your `console.log`, accessing `.LCS.info` from `{}` gives an error. Only after a rerender triggered by `setLCSData(data)` when the `fetch` call returns will `LCS_Data` be the value returned from the API. So in this scenario, you can either:

1. Pass a default value like `{ LCS: { info: 'default info' } }` to useState so that before the `useEffect` runs and the `fetch` call returns, you have a value for `LCS_Data.LCS.info` to be printed out.
2. Use optional chaining (`LCS_Data.LCS?.info`) to print out `undefined` if there is no value yet.

Note that this is how it should work: you will not have the value from the server until the `useEffect` fires and the `fetch` call returns. What you should do is to provide a default value before this happens.